# Unable to get a response from http POST

Tags: python, iptables, twilio

I'm attempting to use twilio to automatically make a few calls for me, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work properly. I'm making phone calls using twilio like this:

```
conn.calls.create(
    to = event.student.phone_number,
    from_ = event.message.teacher.twilio_number,
    url = '%stwilio_calls/%d/' % (BASE_URL, event.id))
```

I'm fairly certain this part of the code is working since I'm receiving calls to my cell as a test.  However, when I get the call it tells me there is an application error.  In the Twilio debug panel, i see this :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3oJZ.png]

It looks like twilio isn't getting a response from my site.  The weird this is that I can navigate to the URL ( `http://166.78.13.45:8000/twilio_calls/19/` ) and receive what looks like properly formatter twiml.  Not sure why twilio can't pick it up.  The view creating this page looks like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def twilio_call(request, event_id):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)

    t = template.Template(event.message.text)
    c = template.Context({'student': event.student})
    call_text = t.render(c)

    # TODO if student not found ?
    # TODO if student.objects.call_notification_ind if false?

    r = twiml.Response()
    r.say(call_text)

    return HttpResponse(str(r))
```

Any ideas what I need to do to get twilio to read this page?

Comment: What is the specific XML error message in your debugger?

Comment: I'm getting a document parse failure (error 12100), with this message:  Error on line 1 of document : Premature end of file. Please ensure that the response body is a valid XML document.

Comment: This means your server is returning XML to Twilio, but it's not properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really strange, and I'm still not sure what caused my issue, but I do have a solution.  Adding the line `print request` in my views.py file seemed to fix it both for this and for another area I'm using this.  I can only imagine that I'm doing something else wrong here, would love if someone could help me figure out why this worked and how to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

From testing the URL, it looks like if you put any data in the POST body, the response body is empty.

```
$ curl -iXPOST http://166.78.13.45:8000/twilio_calls/19/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.6
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2013 00:20:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Say>Hi Dan,

This is a very long test message for you to try out.  Let's see what you think of it.  Give it a shot!!!

Call me back if you have any questions</Say></Response>
```

However adding a CallSid parameter to the request:

```
$ curl -iXPOST http://166.78.13.45:8000/twilio_calls/19/ -d 'foo'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.6
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2013 00:20:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

with no body.

Comment: Any idea why this might be?

Comment: No, but you should check your code for any if/else/return statements that would branch the control flow based on a call sid. Or post the whole code here.

Comment: Just reformatted the method from views.py in the original post, here's the URLconf:     `url(r'^twilio_calls/(\d+)/$', 'teachercomapp.views.twilio_call', name='twilio_call'),`

Comment: It looks like just posting any data in the request body returns the empty response.

Comment: You might want to try print line debugging eg returning from higher up in the function, just to check that the correct route is being called, and that it's doing what you expect.

Comment: So I went ahead and did that and looks like it's calling fine.  I also started playing around with it locally and actually received a response for curl -iXPOST http://localhost/twilio_calls/5/ -d 'Cid=a'.  This makes me think I'm missing something in my server settings.  If it's helpful, I'm running uwsgi on nginx, on a centos box...